# Facet box plots by additional category in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a box plot in Python with the `Seaborn` package (sns) as shown in the code below where the x-axis is age ranges and the y-axis is a dollar value number ('AveMonthSpend').

```
def plot_box(df, col, col_y ='AveMonthSpend'):
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    sns.boxplot(col, col_y, data=df)
    plt.xlabel(col) # Set text for the x axis
    plt.ylabel(col_y)# Set text for y axis
    plt.show()

plot_box(df_3, 'age_range')
```

What I would like to do is facet this box plot by a third column - 'Gender' with the two values being ['M', 'F']. I have read this site and have tried many options, but none seem to work.

[Click here for image of box plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cydC.png)

Following is one of the options I tried:

```html
g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.melt(df, id_vars='Gender'), col='Gender')
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'age_range', 'AveMonthSpend')
```

For this I got the following error:

```
KeyError: "['age_range' 'AveMonthSpend'] not in index"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!